# Cannot receive Ack from Mirth

Tags: tcp, hl7, mirth

I have a testing tcp application which will send HL7 message to Mirth and receiving acknowledgement from Mirth.The problem is that I can send message to Mirth Channel which I created with connector type=TCP Listener but Mirth somehow did not send back acknowledgment to my application.I found that sometimes respone successfully generated and sometimes response successfully send.But I cannot receive any ack message from Mirth.I am a newbie with Mirth and I don't know exactly how to set the channel to receive and send ack message.Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the HL7 message that you are sending to Mirth follows MLLP. It should start with a VT and end with FS CR. See http://www.hl7standards.com/blog/2007/05/02/hl7-mlp-minimum-layer-protocol-defined/

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main settings I am aware of to configure the ACK messages in Mirth.

1. Edit Channel --> Source tab --> Source Settings --> Response --> Change drop down option to one of the Auto-generate options
2. Edit Channel --> Source tab --> Edit Transformer --> Message Templates tab --> Properties (next to Data Type) --> Modify the codes that get used in the ACK messages.

What settings do you currently have set for these?

Comment: I already set for No.1 the same but I cannot find setting for No.2.Thanks.

Comment: No.1 should be enough. Check your test app to see if it's actually receiving anything. In addition you may specify the ACK message manually in Scripts Postprocessor and assign Source Settings - Response to that message.
No.2 is to control auto response generation settings, same as Set Data Types – Source – Inbound – Response Generation (in the list of other v2 settings).

Comment: I also have tcp receiver test app,when I test with my test app with my tcp receiver test app,my test app can receive ack. But when I try to test with mirth,it didn't get ack.How can I specify  ACK message manually in Scripts Postprocessor?Can you tell me more about this or give reference to me.I don't know how to do it.Thanks you so much for your answer.

Comment: May be this can help - mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com